# Complex excel formula ID user, add time for each occurance and find the average

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having trouble with an excel formula. I have a large excel file consisting of user IDs, objectives and time. I am trying to isolate the average time per objective by user. Maybe I am over thinking this formula, but I am hoping that someone can point me in the right direction.

Example:
In this example we look to the master file to determine that user 1 completed, objective 1, 16 times and it took 10 minutes on average to complete objective 1. I really just need the user, the objective and the average time. I am not sure how to write the formula without considering the number of occurrences.

```
{USER ID} {Objective}   {# occurrences} {Avg time / occurrence}
User 1    Objective 1   16           10 minutes
User 1     Objective 2   9            9 minutes
User 5     objective 1   12           10 minutes
```

Example data set

```
| UserID | Objective   | Minutes |   |   |
|--------|-------------|---------|---|---|
| 10001  | Objective 1 | 10      |   |   |
| 10001  | Objective 1 | 12      |   |   |
| 10001  | Objective 1 | 10      |   |   |
| 10001  | Objective 5 | 18      |   |   |
| 10002  | Objective 1 | 19      |   |   |
| 10002  | Objective 1 | 27      |   |   |
| 10002  | Objective 4 | 10      |   |   |
| 10003  | Objective 1 | 11      |   |   |
| 10003  | Objective 1 | 13      |   |   |
| 10003  | Objective 3 | 12
```

example output

```
| User ID | Objective 1 | Objective 2 | Objective 3 | Objective 4 |
|---------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
| 10001   | AVG time    | AVG time    | AVG time    | AVG time    |
| 10002   | AVG time    | AVG time    | AVG time    | AVG time    |
| 10003   | AVG time    | AVG time    | AVG time    | AVG time    |
```

Comment: I can do a pivot table to identify number of occurrences, but I am not sure how to add the average time across all occurrences. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I do not yet have the average time for each objective by user. I am looking to find the average time for each objective by user.

Comment: I have column 1 users column 2 objectives column 3 time. I need to find out how many times each user completed each objective and on average how long it took each user to complete each objective.

Comment: That's not what you are showing in your example.  Please provide both an example of useable data, and an example of your desired output. Try using this [Markdown Table Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to produce a table that we can easily copy/paste into a worksheet.

Comment: Put your table in your original question. You may notice it is hard to read when it is in a comment.

Comment: Well, first and foremost I appreciate your help. the tables are still pasting weird. I can format them as soon as I have a chance.

Comment: The only thing needed, to format, was to select the table and then select the `Code Sample` `{..}` icon as I did.

Answer (score 0):

Given that data, all you need is a Pivot Table

- Drag UserID to the Rows area
- Objective to the Columns area
- Minutes to the Values area

  - Select Average for Value settings
  - Select an appropriate number format for num of decimals

[image]

Comment: Well... Thank you, I guess I really over thought this. Thanks for the help. I regret starting a thread for a pivot table.

Comment: @FullStack sometimes it just takes a fresh pair of eyes